# Mootools Add href url inside a events click function

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a script that I'm trying to add a HREF url in the events click function ::: When a button is clicked the script is supposed to initiate the MilkBox (lightbox) ::: My Javascript is very limited but I was able to add the "HREF url" to the title attribute as you can see below (to test), as I have it below it works good, but when I move the '+fullurl+' to the HREF it fails. It then is unable to load the url ::: The lightbox initiates with an empty URL :::

```
$("wall").addEvents({

    "mouseover:relay(div.tile)": function() {
        var play = this.retrieve("play");
        if (!play) {
            play = new Element("div", {
                styles: {
                    position: "absolute",
                    marginTop: 120,
                    marginLeft: 120,
                    width: 32,
                    height: 32
                },
                "title": "Click to play",
                "class": "cur hide",
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            var tubeObject = this.getParent().retrieve("tubeObject");
                            var tubeObject = this.getParent().retrieve("tubeObject")
                            var fullurl = tubeObject.full;

                                milkbox.openWithFile({ 
                                    href:'http://localhost/square/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/34.jpg', 
                                    title:''+fullurl+''
                                });
                        }
                    },
                html: "<img src='http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CornerStone/PNG/play.png' />"
            }).inject(this, "top");
            this.store("play", play);
        }
        play.removeClass("hide");
    },
    "mouseout:relay(div.tile)": function() {
        this.retrieve("play").addClass("hide");
    }

});
```

Comment: put it as answer and mark it as accepted, so this question will be marked as 'resolved' ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue ::: Its my (custom) TimThumb function that caused it not to work ::: Bottom line the script works :::